# Why is tearDown for in testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, nose, nosetests

I understand that setUp is necessary because you may have to initialize some variables before running the test (please correct me if I'm wrong) but what is the tearDown for? Is it to delete all the variables created on the setUp? If so, when closing the cmd woundn't it already clear up the data? This is confusing for me.

I'm in particular using NoseTests with Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

`setUp` and `tearDown` are executed for *each* test. So no, 'closing the cmd' wouldn't do it, because that only happens at the end of the entire test suite.

The idea is that you have a consistent starting point for every single test, and these two methods are responsible for setting that up at the beginning, and putting things back the way they were at the end.